# Get Per-Email Statistics From Amazon SES in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I can now **Send Bulk Emails With AWS SES Service**. Now I want to get Per-Email statistics for all these emails I've sent

I want to display **each email statistics** on a dashboard developed in **ASP.NET C#**

Per mail, How can I get **Send, Delivered, Blocked, Opened, Clicked** statistics from SES

I have access to **SNS** and **SQS** services. How can the help me?
How can I use **ASP.Net C#** capturing these statistics from Amazon? Do I need to use their SDK or Webhook like that

What should be the logic I need to follow to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

For the first three points you can use my project on GitHub. You must only configure the SNS webhooks to https.[Nager.AmazonSesNotification](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonSesNotification)

```cs
[Route("SesNotification")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SesNotificationAsync()
{
    var body = string.Empty;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    var notificationProcessor = new NotificationProcessor();
    var result = await notificationProcessor.ProcessNotificationAsync(body);

    //Your processing logic...

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
 }
```